# Converged value of ecutwfc in Quantum Espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso

[image]

Which is my ecutwfc converged value in this calculation result.

How to choose ecutrho in quantum espresso calculation.

Answer (score 7):

Convergence is always defined in term of tolerance what user choose and based on your data, I will take `ecutwfc` as 70 Ryd. You should also report run time along with these data.
For considering `ecutrho` I will suggest you to stick with default value, if you are dealing with metallic system.

> Kinetic energy cutoff (Ry) for charge density and potential:
> For norm-conserving pseudopotential you should stick to the
> default value, you can reduce it by a little but it will
> introduce noise especially on forces and stress.
> If there are ultrasoft PP, a larger value than the default is
> often desirable (ecutrho = 8 to 12 times ecutwfc, typically).
> PAW datasets can often be used at 4*ecutwfc, but it depends
> on the shape of augmentation charge: testing is mandatory.
> The use of gradient-corrected functional, especially in cells
> with vacuum, or for pseudopotential without non-linear core
> correction, usually requires an higher values of ecutrho
> to be accurately converged.

**References:**

https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm274

Answer (score 1):

You can choose E-E_best value to be less than 0.01 eV (magnitude) per atom. The E_best is the highest ecutwfc (110 Ry) you considered.

So 40 Ry is a rough idea to consider, seeing your results. Though you need to do the kpoint convergence as well to get final decision.